# Failed to build app with Maven, I can run code locally, but fail to deploy on heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

This is my code in github:
https://github.com/q463746583/CS4500-Assignment2
I can run it successfully in the local,
but while I try to deploy the code on heroku,
There is the error description:

```
       [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.jar (317 kB at 6.0 MB/s)
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /tmp/build_3c4f3b86a26f6e3ae1cbe89639f79f26/target/classes
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 13.261 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-24T00:47:07Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TLDR:**

1. Ensure you're **using the appropriate JAVA JDK**
2. Check that your **target environment from the Maven compiler is the same as your targeted Heroku JAVA runtime**.
3. If you're **not using the default JAVA 8 JDK** runtime environment **create a system.properties file in your project specifying a different supported JAVA runtime enviroment** as listed within Heroku's JAVA buildpack documentation.

---

I think this has to do with a **mismatch** between your **targeted Java runtime environment on Heroku** and your **locally compiled code, generated from the Maven compiler,** which you're trying to push to Heroku.

*According to Heroku's [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions):*

Heroku currently uses **OpenJDK 8 to run your application by default**. OpenJDK versions 9 and 7 are also available.

Other supported default versions are:

- Java 7 - 1.7.0_181
- Java 8 - 1.8.0_191
- Java 9 - 9.0.4
- Java 10 - 10.0.2
- Java 11 - 11

So you should make sure that within your **pom.xml** file that your *maven compiler is compiling your JAVA code to the appropriate JAVA buildpack you're targeting on Heroku*. For example, below we are targeting a Java 7 runtime environment:

**pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then you should **create a `system.properties` file in your project if you're targeting a runtime environment other than Heroku's default JDK 1.8** runtime environment. You can do this by specifying your desired java runtime environment like such:

**system.properties**:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while deploying the git project in Heroku. I just changed `java.version` to **8** from 11 in `pom.xml` and it worked for me:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the previous answers, creating a system.properties file, making a new commit with that change and rerunning the heroku command fixed the issue for me.

[image]

Also, please be mindful about the name of your branch if you're **not using main as your main branch** as that would require a match such as.

```
git push heroku master:main
```

or

```
git push heroku develop:main
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove this error, simply add one extra file into your repository with the name `system.application` and

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the approaches, but none worked.

---

**SOLUTION**: *Remove* all the references to your Java version in your `pom.xml`, i.e.

```
<properties>    
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```